# POWERBI Change order of a column in matrix by different alphabet than english

Tags: powerbi

I need to change the order of columns in powerBI by different alphabet than english. We have special characters in our country and english alphabet sorts the order differently than our alphabet.

Is there any possiblity to change the order based on different country alphabet order?

There is possiblity to add index and order by index, but it`s only temporary solution until new words with special characters come.

Therefore I would need to change alphabet to solve the issue permanently.

However I am not sure whether this is possible, but I try.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Power BI supports 44 languages. Based on the language chosen the sorting and comparing also changes. Below is the link that explains how to change the language step-by-step.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/supported-languages-countries-regions

Hope it helps.